# Create an HTML file with R

Tags: javascript, html, r, google-maps

What I'm wondering is, would it be possible to create an HTML file from R ? I will be setting up R to work on the server side, and it will be making an heatmap overlay, and hopefully if it is possible to make an HTML file from R, I can just add in the image and set it up so it will be using Google maps, using the heatmap overlay.

[This is the code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) I'm looking at and in there the overlay is given two coordinates, North east and south west, along with a center to specify where the map is.

In R when the overlay has been created, I can also save the coordinates, north east and south west along with the center of where the map should go. But what if I don't make the HTML file in R? How can I get these coordinates and delete previous overlay and place the new one on top and update it with the new coordinates?

Comment: Overlays can be added onto a Google Map in R as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44792035/5977215)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It's simple if you use RStudio to build a RMarkdown with knitr.

http://yihui.name/knitr/

If you want to use the data in R, you can echo it and assign it to javascript variables and functions. Here's an example

http://al2na.github.io/Rmarkdown_JSviz/