# Google Chart Overlays using googleVis package in R

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

Google Charts has overlay functionality that allows you to put an image over a plot at a specified position. Is this possible in the `googleVis` package or do I need to edit the chart `html` ad hoc to include an overlay?

Comment: Are you using `knitr` to produce your output? If so, I suspect that you could figure out something with the `includes` YAML parameter as shown here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#includes. Following the overlay documentation (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays#overview), you'd need to position the styling information before the chart script generated by `googleVis` and body information after.

Comment: No. I am using R to produce the code for Google Chart, then editing that code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overlay to a Google map using my `googleway` package.
To use Google Maps you need a valid API key

```
library(googleway)
map_key <- 'your_api_key'

google_map(key = map_key) %>%
    add_overlay(north = 40.773941,south = 40.712216, east = -74.12544, west = -74.22655,
                            overlay_url = "https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg")
```

[image]